# What is "app_exception" event in Firebase?

Tags: firebase

How is it different from the crashes reported in Firebase? Also, how can I get what exactly exception has occurred?

Firebase documentation does not mention that.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to provide more context?  As it's phrased now, it's really difficult to understand what you're asking.

Comment: I think it is "Event and parameter details (Google Analytics for Firebase)","app_exception".